# How do I selectively turn off video to monitors?

Tags: video

I'm running a 3 screen setup currently.  2 nice matte Samsungs that I do all my work on and one glossy Apple screen that has the camera and microphone on it.  I want to continue to use the camera and microphone on the Apple screen for my video conferences, but I don't want video to go to it any more/have apps see it as a valid screen and pop up on it.  So, ideally I just disable it in the display control panel, but I don't see any options to do so.

Ran across a GitHub project that claims to do so, but when I tell it to power off one monitor they ALL power down, so that's not going to work...  Any other ideas?  Even if it's a shell script I have to run on each boot I'm fine with that.  I basically never want video to go to that monitor so I don't need a fancy UI.

Comment: What happens if you just switch the monitor off? Doesn't that achieve what you want?

Comment: If I turn the monitor off then the microphone and camera shut off too.  I want to use the microphone and camera but not have the display be an active part of my desktop (I don't control my environment and the glossy screen has terrible glare with our overhead lighting, so having apps insist on using it is tremendously annoying).

Comment: Ah, okay, so you're holding a lot of video conferences and it's not practical to just switch it on when you're having one. Gotcha.

Comment: A contributing factor is that I do a lot of remote desktop work as well and remote desktop locks up when I have 3 monitors on.  It comes back to life as soon as I turn that monitor off, but with video conferences throughout the day...  I put the monitor on a power strip so I can keep turning it on/off, but this is definitely not an ideal solution.  On a Windows box I'd just disable that screen output and still be able to use the devices on it.  I'd figure Apple should have something comparable.